# Silverlight SecurityException while accessing php rest

Tags: php, silverlight, rest

im trying to access a php rest service on a different server with silverlight, but everytime i do the

```
request.EndGetResponse(ar) as HttpWebResponse;
```

it throws a SecurityException any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [URL Access Restrictions in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008%28VS.95%29.aspx):

Also try adding the `<allow-from http-request-headers="*">` statement in the clientaccesspolicy.xml on the php site.

When in doubt, run fiddler so you can see the exact sequence of web calls.